# VScode python not ouput

Tags: python

Why is there no output in my vs code python.

[image]

Comment: Is your code valid? I mean, the space between `print` and `(`

Comment: Why should a space not be allowed? Something like `print   (  'Hi')` is no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try saving your file before running it.

You can do this very quickly using the shortcut `Crtl + S`.

Comment: Here is a link on how to autosave which may help when things like this occur - https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-toggle-auto-save-in-vs-code/#:~:text=To%20turn%20on%20or%20turn,Mac%3A%20Code%20%3E%20Preferences%20%3E%20Settings

Answer (score 0):

first you have to save your code by pressing **ctrl+s**.
By default python output will be displayed on Vscode "**Terminal**".
To display the result in "**Output**" use "**Code Runner**" extension.

---

[Code Runner extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TQqr.png)